# RecyclerView onItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm looking to build a program where someone will click from a list of text and this will take them to another activity.

I'm aware that RecyclerView doesn't have a listener for clicks, like ListView but, after several attempts, I am unable to get this to work.

Below is the code I have attempted to implement:

MyChatRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class MyChatRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyChatRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Chat> mValues;
    private final OnItemClickListener listener;
    //private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MyChatRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Chat> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mValues = items;
        //mListener = listener;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.bind(mValues.get(position), listener);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != listener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    listener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        //public void onItemClick(View view , int position);
        void onItemClick(Chat item);
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public Chat mItem;
        OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

        /*@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
            }
        }*/

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            mIdView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mContentView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        public void bind(final Chat item, final OnItemClickListener listener){

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the tutorial I have attempted to follow: https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

Comment: You call the interface in your Activity, right?

Comment: Did you set mIdView.setClickable(true)?

Answer (score 2):

Inside a `RecyclerView`, views are recycled to improve performance. You shouln't place the `OnClickListener` inside the `onBindViewHolder` as the position will not always be correct.
Try moving the `OnClickListener` inside the constructor of the `ViewHolder` and getting the current position by calling `getAdapterPosition()` :

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mIdView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mContentView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);

        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (null != listener) {     
                    listener.onListFragmentInteraction(mValues.get(position));
                }
           }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add following method to your MyChatRecyclerViewAdapter :

```
public void setClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
this.listener = listener;
}
```

and call

```
mAdapter.setClickListener(new MyChatRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Chat chat) {

            }
});
```

from your Activity/Fragment class

Answer (score 0):

You are setting onclick listener 2 times. 1 in onBind() and 1 in View holder.

Remove from on Bind() and in view holder use listener object to pass event to specific listener.

```
Layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (getListener() != null) {
                        getListener().onLayoutClick(view, this.getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {

 //inflate the view 
  View view =LayoutInflator.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layoutID,null);

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);

    //here we can set onClicklistener
    view.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListeener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //Your action stuff
        }
    });

return holder;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ReactiveAdapter extends 

RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
String[] mDataset = { "Data", "In", "Adapter" };

private final PublishSubject<String> onClickSubject = PublishSubject.create();

@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final String element = mDataset[position];

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           onClickSubject.onNext(element);
        }
    });
}

public Observable<String> getPositionClicks(){
    return onClickSubject.asObservable();
}
```

}

Comment: copy/pasting from another well explained answer in another post is not a nice thing to do. At least care enough to put a reference to the original answer.